# undefined reference to `printf' in cross-compilation using clang

Tags: c, gcc, include, clang, cross-compiling

I execute below code to create .o file

```
   clang --target=i686-pc-none-elf -march=i386 -c fcfs.c -o fcfs.o -std=gnu90 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wall
```

and then while I execute below code

```
i686-elf-ld -T linker.ld -o JOS.bin fcfs.o
```

I got error says

```
**fcfs.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `fopen'
fcfs.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `fgets'
fcfs.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `printf'**
```

my fcfs.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char dataToBeRead[50];
    int a = abs(-5);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("process.txt", "r");
    // int fp=1;
    printf("%d", a);
    int s;
    if(fp != NULL){
        printf("File is not empty");

          while( fgets ( dataToBeRead, 50, fp ) != NULL ) 
        { 
          
            // Print the dataToBeRead  
            printf( "%s" , dataToBeRead ) ; 
         } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why I am getting this error.
Do I need to add some more arguments to clang related to library linking?
Can I use gcc libraries in clang?
Or it is problem of `i686-elf-ld` ?

Comment: Header files are not libraries. They provide only declarations that describe the functions, not the actual object modules that implement the functions. To link a complete program, you need to include the files that contain the function implementations. The Clang and GCC commands to compile and build include these by default when linking. But if you are trying to do some special or cross-tools link, you may need to include the files in the link command explicitly.

Comment: Note that the library commonly used with GCC is the GNU C Library, not a GCC library *per se*. I do not know whether the Clang you have installed would work with the GNU C Library you have installed.

Comment: That solved my doubt and thank you for correcting me on header files and libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang do support header files like `stdio`.h , `stdlib.h` and other header files.

If you are facing issue like

```
fcfs.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `fopen'
fcfs.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `printf'
```

in clang you can solve it by adding `--sysroot` to your clang options.
In my case

```
   clang --target=i686-pc-none-elf -march=i386 --sysroot=/usr -c fcfs.c -o fcfs.o -std=gnu90 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wall
```

In this case **`-sysroot`** will start looking for header files from `/usr` folder. In /usr it will find folders like `/bin ,/include ,etc`. and when it goes to /include folder it will find all header files and that will solve problem.

for more info refer https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html